# Wrappers for inb() and outb() linux syscalls

Tags: c, linux, go, system-calls

Are there any Go wrappers for the following Linux syscalls used for low-level port input-output?

```
#include <sys/io.h>

unsigned char inb(unsigned short int port);
void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short int port);
```

I have only managed to find a wrapper for sister call:

```
int ioperm(unsigned long from, unsigned long num, int turn_on);
```

which sets access to aforementioned ports. Wrapper is in syscall Go package:

```
func Ioperm(from int, num int, on int) (err error)
```

but not a trace of **inb()** and **outb()**. I do not want to use **cgo** for this calls to not lose easy cross-compilation.

Comment: While `ioperm` _is_ a syscall, `inb` and `outb` are _not_ syscalls. They just issue a machine inst of (e.g. `inb` or `outb`), and _can_ be implemented as inline functions and/or inline asm statements.

Comment: Those are not syscalls, but assembly instructions, I'm afraid you'll need a C module and `cgo` for that.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, thanks for the answer! I was planning to implement a little logic around those functions in pure Go. But the module itself is not so big so instead of doing Go + cgo it will be much easier for me to do it in plain C.

Comment: @PavelSilin I might suggest to use Go and cgo. Go is safer in many aspects and is easier to write error-checked code in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inb` and `outb` are not system calls, they are processor instructions. You can write wrapper functions in C for these and call them with `cgo`.

Here's the C functions (unless you do have them available in `sys/io.h`):

```
unsigned char inb(unsigned short port)
{
    unsigned char ret;
    asm volatile("in %%dx, %%al" : "=a"(ret) : "d"(port) : "memory");
    return ret;
}

void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short port)
{
    asm volatile("out %%al, %%dx" : : "a"(value), "d"(port) : "memory");
}
```

And a little header file you can use with `cgo`:

```
#ifndef IOPORT_H_
#define IOPORT_H_ 1

unsigned char inb(unsigned short port);
void outb(unsigned char value, unsigned short port);

#endif
```

Comment: No, `inb`/`outb` instructions _can_ be issued from userspace. That's what the `ioperm` (and/or `iopl`) syscall does. It maps a range of I/O ports into the user process space so they can be accessed by the process.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks for letting me know. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @CraigEstey, well both `ioperm` and `outb` have `man(2)` entry for it. That is why I was thinking that as `ioperm` is a syscall (and has Go wrapper) so `outb` is a syscall as well.

Comment: @PavelSilin Yeah, some of the man(2) pages are misleading. I noticed that a while ago too.

Comment: You're going to want `asm volatile` to make sure the read still happens even if the result is unused.  And probably a `"memory"` clobber for ordering wrt. possible MMIO access.

Comment: @PeterCordes Fixed.

Comment: Oh, also note that you can use an `"Nd"(port)` constraint to allow immediate port numbers for port numbers 0..255.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples